# Can I aggregate data from a stream on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have data coming from multiple machines, I would like to aggregate it by user. I'm thinking of producing batches of 1000 "rows", or 10 seconds of data (whichever comes first), by user.

I do have some experience with AWS kinesis and lambdas, but in my experience we don't have so much control on how the aggregation is done. All machines would send the data by kinesis, with the user id as the partition key. Then AWS will call our lambda with small batches. This has been great for some other use cases but here if I receive 100 records I don't know what to do (I would like to "wait" to receive more or wait that 10 seconds elapse since the date of the first record).

Also I'm not sure how the aggregation "by user id" would work. So far, on a lambda, I would have split the records in the batch by user id, but then if I get called with a batch of 100 records, even though there is a partition key on the user id, there is no guarantee that those 100 records would be for 1 user. Maybe I will get 100 records from 100 different users, and there is no "aggregation" help at all.

Any idea if kinesis + lambda is suited for this? I did look at the documentation of AWS but I don't see my scenario. It looks like they also have a tool "Data Streams" but it's hard for me to understand if this would work for my case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct. AWS Lambda + Kinesis alone will not be sufficient alone for aggregation. AWS Lambda programming model is stateless, so you can only aggregate based on the batch of records received in that particular invocatio(GetRecords API) call. Furthermore, the batch size provided in the function does not gurantee that you will get that number of records. This is merely the maximum number of records which you can get(MaxRecords) per invocation.

What you need is some kind of windowing mechanism, either row-based or time-based. [Kinesis Analytics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/windowed-sql.html) would be the easiest and fastest to get on-boarded with this. You can either use SQL or Flink with Kinesis analytics. You can even have your output to AWS Lambda for post processing.

Other ways would be use a Spark streaming job (you can use AWS EMR) and use windowing in your application.